# php can not load extension

Tags: php, apache

I have...

> 1.compiled and made ssh2.so.
>
> 2.placed the PHP extension (ssh2.so) in the "extension_dir" 
>   3.been editing the correct php.ini file (extension=ssh2.so), the file "Loaded
>   Configuration File" entry listed in the phpinfo() output. 
>   4.restarted apache server.

but, "php -m" prints no ssh2 module.

any idea?

Comment: Restarting Apache has no effect on 'php -m' and if the module failed loading it would tell you why if you set the display_startup_errors to On

Comment: What happens with get_loaded_extensions() - does that reveal it? There's also extension_loaded() to test. Finally, you can try loading with dl() at run time?

Comment: thank you jack, you gave me the point.

Answer (score 3):

For `php -m` to show the ssh2 module, you have to *edit the CLI php.ini* for that.

There are generally TWO php.ini, one for Apache module and the other for the CLI version of PHP.

In Ubuntu, you will edit `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, but YMMV

Oh, and the syntax is very much the same, so a copy-paste should do the job.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

It is not `php -m` that you want to do but rather to create a php file in your web site containing:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Accessing this via Apache will show you what modules are loaded. You may want to configure Apache to secure access to this.

Comment: The question says he tried this, and it was good. Just php -m that didn't show.

Comment: Doh! Yep, voted up the other answer. Reminder to self: don't answer questions when pushed for time!